# Publish files to bin folder when source files are in a sub-folder with ClickOnce with WPF app

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have found numerous articles on StackOverflow and elsewhere stating that if you wanted to output your files to the bin folder using ClickOnce, you should set the

`BuildAction`: `Content`

`CopyToOuputDirectory` : `Copy if newer`

but some of my binaries are located in a `Dependencies` subfolder located in the root of my project and when I publish the content, they are being outputted to

`<wpf app folder>\dependencies` instead of being in the `<wpf app folder>` causing my app to not function properly.

Any suggestions on how I can change this to force `ClickOnce` to output specific files to `<wpf app folder>\` irrespective of where the `Source files` are located.

Comment: Click on project -> Properies -> Build -> Output->Output Path, end just add ../Debug instead of Debug, or some other relative path

Comment: The issue is not with the build location but with how ClickOnce outputs files that are contained in subfolders to the same subfolder when installed when I want specific files to be copied in the root folder of the application,.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a work-around which I don't like but I need to move on. To circumvent this problem I added the required libraries to the root of my project as links and still set the `BuildAction` to `Content` and `CopyToOutputDirectory` to `Copy if newer`.

I thought I'd explain it with an example as it may make a bit more sense.

Project Path: C:\Work\MyApp and it contains the following sub-folders:

D:\Work\MyApp\MyApp.csproj
D:\Work\MyApp\MyApp.xaml
...
D:\Work\MyApp\Bin\Debug
D:\Work\MyApp\Bin\Release
D:\Work\MyApp\Bin\Release\MyApp.exe
D:\Work\MyApp\Depedencies\LibA.dll
D:\Work\MyApp\Depedencies\LibB.dll
etc...

The libraries are third-party tools and are actually contained in their own folder:

D:\Tools\MyThirdPartyLib\Distributation\LibA.dll
D:\Tools\MyThirdPartyLib\Distributation\LibB.dll

By having the libraries in D:\Work\MyApp\Dependencies did not work as `ClickOnce` would install the app in:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...\MyApp.exe

and it installed the files located in the Dependencies sub-folder in:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...\Dependencies\LibA.dll
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...\Dependencies\LibB.dll

Which caused my app not to work.

To get around it, I ended up adding LibA.dll and LibB.dll to the root of my project as "Linked files" and set their `BuildAction` and `CopyToOutputDirectory` but not by pointing the linked files to

D:\Work\MyApp\Depedencies\LibA.dll
D:\Work\MyApp\Depedencies\LibB.dll

but instead pointing them:

D:\Tools\MyThirdPartyLib\Distributation\LibA.dll
D:\Tools\MyThirdPartyLib\Distributation\LibB.dll

And this seems to have done the trick. My only beef about it is that now I've got 10 odd files listed in the root of my project in visual studio which I don't like:

```
MyApp Solution
    - MyApp Project
        - MyApp.csproj
        - MyApp.xaml
        - ...
        - LibA.dll
        - LibB.dll
        - ...
```

But it will have to do for now.

Hope it helps others!